# Most Pythonic way to handle splitting a class into multiple classes

Tags: python

I have a class that can interface with either Oracle or MySQL.  The class is initialized with a keyword of either "Oracle" or "MySQL" and a few other parameters that are standard for both database types (what to print, whether or not to stop on an exception, etc.).

It was easy enough to add `if Oracle do A, elif MySQL do B` as necessary when I began, but as I add more specialized code that only applies to one database type, this is becoming ugly.  I've split the class into two, one for Oracle and one for MySQL, with some shared functions to avoid duplicate code.

What is the most Pythonic way to handle calling these new classes?  Do I create a wrapper function/class that uses this same keyword and returns the correct class?  Do I change all of my code that calls the old generic class to call the correct DB-specific class?

I'll gladly mock up some example code if needed, but I didn't think it was necessary.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I create a wrapper function/class that uses this same keyword and returns the correct class?

That's the idea. Such a function is called a factory function:

```
def connect_to(db, *args):
    if db == "MySQL":
        return MySQL(*args)
    elif db == "Oracle":
        return Oracle(*args)
    else:
        raise ValueError("unknown database type: %r" % db)
```

Make sure that both database classes have the same API. You can achieve this either with duck typing or with abstract base classes (ABCs); the latter are mostly useful if functionality is shared between the classes, or if you want to do `isinstance` checks to find out if an object represents a database connection.

In the case of shared functionality, the [template method pattern](http://www.aleax.it/gdd_pydp.pdf) often comes in handy.

Answer (score 3):

Create a factory class which returns an implementation based on the parameter. You can then have a common base class for both DB types, one implementation for each and let the factory create, configure and return the correct implementation to the user based on a parameter.

This works well when the two classes behave very similarly; but as soon as you want to use DB specific features, it gets ugly because you need methods like `isFeatureXSupported()` (good approach) or `isOracle()` (more simple but bad since it moves knowledge of which DB has which feature from the helper class into the app code).

Alternatively, you can implement all features for both and throw an exception when one isn't supported. In your code, you can then look for the exception to check this. This makes the code more clean but now, you can really check whether a feature is available without actually using it. That can cause problems in the app code (when you want to disable menus, for example, or when the app could do it some other way).

Comment: Good advice, but unless your factory class is also the base class, you might as well just use a factory function.

Comment: Using a factory class is useful when you need to configure it. Otherwise, you get a function with too many parameters.